# CouchDB per field read privilege based on roles

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I'm new with CouchDB.
I don't know if I can restrict the fields that a role can read from a document. If I can, is this the right approach to work with CouchDB?

For example, if I have a document like this:

```
{
    firstname: 'firstname',
    lastname: 'lastname',
    email: ['home': 'foobar@foobar.net', 'work': 'foobar@foobar-working.net'],
    phone: ['home': '+81 00 0000 0000'],
}
```

And the following roles:

```
{
   "admins": {
       "names": [
           "superuser"
       ],
       "roles": [
           "admins"
       ]
   },
   "members": {
       "names": [
           "user1",
           "user2"
       ],
       "roles": [
           "developers"
       ]
   }
}
```

I want that admin roles can read all the fields while developers can read only email and phone.
How can I achieve this? Using validation functions?

Answer (score 3):

The functionality described in your post is not available in CouchDB.

The security in couchdb is defined in the following terms (extracted from doc)

> The security object consists of two compulsory elements, admins and members, which are used to specify the list of users and/or roles that have admin and members rights to the database respectively:
>
> - **members**: they **can read all types of documents** from the DB, and they
>     can write (and edit) documents to the DB except for design documents.
> - **admins**: they have all the privileges of members plus the privileges:
>     **write (and edit) design documents**, add/remove database admins and
>     members and set the database revisions limit. They can not create a
>     database nor delete a database.

There is not per-document or even per-partial-document access restrictions implemented in CouchDB

Currently, you can define per-document write restrictions by defining a Validate Document Update funcion in a Desing Document.

There is a proposal for adding some per-document access restriction but it seems to be in the early stages of development. You can see the proposal [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/6aa77dd8e5974a3a540758c6902ccb509ab5a2e4802ecf4fd724a5e4@%3Cdev.couchdb.apache.org%3E).

Comment: Ok thanks does exists another method to achieve the result I need?

Comment: There are not built-in mechanisms in CouchDB for your requirements. You should some logic on top of CouchDB for supporting it. It depends on your architecture.